# Reading the socket buffer

Tags: sockets, tcp, ftp, client, buffer

I am attempting to write an FTP Client and I need to print out the server response to my commands. One of these commands is STAT. The server returns the response and as I understand it the response is in the socket buffer which I can read using the read() command. The problem is I only need the response for STAT so I know it will end with END OF STATUS. This is the code I wrote to read the response:

```
in = read(connFd, &timebuffer, sizeof(timebuffer));;
while(in>0){
    printf("%s", timebuffer);
    memset(&timebuffer, 0, sizeof timebuffer);
    in = read(connFd, &timebuffer, sizeof(timebuffer));
}
memset(&timebuffer, 0, sizeof timebuffer);
```

The problem I am getting is that once the read() function goes through the buffer and finishes reading the while loop does not terminate and continues infinitely, my program just sits there. I assume it is because the read() function is waiting for data so I was wondering if there is a way to tell read() to stop once the end of the buffer is reached. I thought this would happen automagically since read() would return something x<1 but if it is waiting I understand what the problem is. So how would I fix it? Is there a way to set up a timeout(0) so it would only read data if it is there already? Also I know there are "flags" that I set to 0 but I can't find much info on them. I appreciate any help. Would the only way be to check for "END OF STATUS" string in the buffer? Would I use strstr(buffer)

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a blocking call (unless you've set the socket to be non-blocking) and so will only return once its received the exact number of bytes you've requested or the socket gets closed.

If the socket is set to be non-blocking then you will get a zero return to "read" but you may get that even when you haven't reached the end of your response because your program will certainly be faster than the network.

As an additional note...  You can't use `strstr()` unless you concatenate all your reads.  You could get 1/2 of the terminate message in one read and the remaining in the next read.